# Custom gradle task that accesses top-level fails with "The constructor ... should be annotated with @Inject"

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to create a re-usable gradle task that accesses something from the top level. This works:

```
val foo = 42

tasks.register("foosimple") {
    println(foo)
}
```

But using a modified example from [Developing Custom Gradle Task Types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:writing_a_simple_task_class) does not:

```
open class Foo : DefaultTask() {
    @TaskAction
    fun foo() {
        println(foo)
    }
}
tasks.register<Foo>("foo")
```

which fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'keycloak-spi'.
> Could not create task ':foo'.
   > Could not create task of type 'Foo'.
      > The constructor for type Build_gradle.Foo should be annotated with @Inject.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Can somebody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here? If I replace `foo()`'s content with `println(42)` it works, of course. But I actually *want* to access something from the top level...

## Further Details

`--stacktrace` wasn't helpful to me:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'keycloak-spi'.
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.getExistingTask(TaskNameResolver.java:116)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.access$000(TaskNameResolver.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver$MultiProjectTaskSelectionResult.collect(TaskNameResolver.java:177)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver$MultiProjectTaskSelectionResult.collectTasks(TaskNameResolver.java:169)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.selectWithName(TaskNameResolver.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:82)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
```

I therefore tried to add an `@Inject` annotation on the constructor a instructed, but apparently, just like me, gradle doesn't know `@Inject`:

```
open class Foo @Inject constructor()  : DefaultTask() {
    @TaskAction
    fun foo() {
        println(foo)
    }
}
```

which fails with:

```
Line 70: class Foo @Inject constructor() {}
                  ^ Unresolved reference: Inject
```

This was the only suggestion by Intellij:

```
open class Foo @javax.inject.Inject constructor()  : DefaultTask() {
    @TaskAction
    fun foo() {
        println(foo)
    }
}
```

Now it fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'keycloak-spi'.
> Could not create task ':foo'.
   > Could not create task of type 'Foo'.
      > 0
```

So now it accepts the `@Inject` annotation, but still doesn't work. I now give up and ask you guys...

Comment: Thanks for answering my question "how to do it then" right in the first code snippet!

Answer (score 15):

Kotlin compiler adds secretly a parameter to generated `Foo` constructor every time you use variables from the build script. That parameter is a reference to the enclosing build script.

As a result the task class has no parameter-less constructors and Gradle assumes then that dependency injection should kick in. But it cannot as generated constructor `Foo(BuildScript_XXX)` has no `@Inject` annotation.

If you want to use script variables in your task you should use input properties, for example:

```
val foo = 42

open class Foo : DefaultTask() {
    @Input
    var fooToPrint: Int = 0

    @TaskAction
    fun foo() {
        println(fooToPrint)
    }
}
tasks.register<Foo>("foo") {
    fooToPrint = foo
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense but the reported error could be better. Gradle is entirely way too much magic.

Comment: Gradle is powerful which also means you can easily shoot yourself in the foot. And indeed the error message is not very helpful.
@PeterV.Mørch is there anything missing in my answer that prevents you from accepting it?